# parsing json like text output with shell or sed/awk?

Tags: json, shell, parsing, awk, sed

I am wondering if anyone seen this text pattern before and know how to parse the package, result and info. It looks like json, but its not.

I am trying to use shell and sed, but so far unable to get the values.

```
load-server {
    package ha
    result false
    info [LOAD_SERVER[com.ha]]
}
load-server {
    package vserver
    result true
}
load-server {
    package virt-lan
    result true
}
load-server {
    package hdd-sda1
    result true
}
load-server {
    package memory
    result true
}
load-server {
    package netmon
   result true
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Show your desired output.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? What do you need to do with this information?